# What kind of Text object are axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Axis labels (`axis.xaxis.label`) appear to be `matplotlib.text.Text` objects, but when extracting the position and attempting to manually create text at the same position, there appears to be a large offset. In the example below, I expect the red "x" would exactly overlap the black one, but it does not.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
label = ax.xaxis.label
pos = label.get_position()
pos_display = label.get_transform().transform(pos)
label_red = plt.text(pos_display[0], pos_display[1], 'x', transform=None, fontdict={'color': 'r'})
plt.show()
```

[image: Script output]

Furthermore, I wasn't able to deep-copy the label `Text` object. In the example below, I expect that a blue "x" would overlap the black one, but it just doesn't show in the figure. If instead of `label` I attempt to replicate `label_red`, then indeed a blue "x" overlaps the red one.

```py
from copy import copy
label_blue = copy(label)
label_blue.set_color('b')
ax.add_artist(label_blue)
plt.show()
```

So, what's so special about the axis label text objects? My end goal is to have a secondary label on the same axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Matplotlib objects do not know their true position until draw time.  This is particularly true for anything that has a position relative to some other artist.  We can force a draw without actually creating the plot using `fig.draw_without_rendering`, and then the label's position is known.  Also, the xlabel has a different vertical and horizontal alignment to the default when using `ax.text` (or `plt.text`), so you need to specify these to match (see *ha* and *va* keywords below).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
fig.draw_without_rendering()

label = ax.xaxis.label
pos = label.get_position()
pos_display = label.get_transform().transform(pos)
label_red = plt.text(pos_display[0], pos_display[1], 'x', transform=None,
                     fontdict={'color': 'r'}, va='top', ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to inspect the artist and tell whether or not its position is going to change at draw time?

Comment: I guess the `stale` attribute is something like that https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.stale.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.stale