# How to align text with the edge of the rightmost element in a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, colorbar

The following code aligns some text to the right edge of the color bar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
img = plt.imshow(data, cmap='viridis')
color_bar = plt.colorbar(img, orientation='vertical')

color_bar.set_label('Color Bar Label', rotation=270, labelpad=15)

color_bar_position = color_bar.ax.get_position()

color_bar_width = color_bar_position.width

plt.text(color_bar_position.x1 + color_bar_width,1.02,'Right-Aligned Text', ha='right', va='center', transform=color_bar.ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

How can I edit this so the text is aligned with the right edge of the color bar label (denoted by the red line) - i.e. the right edge of the rightmost element in the figure below? This figure is just an example; I need to apply this to a much more complex piece of code, so I need to be able to extract the x-direction figure coordinate of this edge to specify the text position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `annotate` instead of `text` then you can specify the x- and y- positions relative to different artists or axes, or various axes/figure coordinates.  Note that axis label positions are not known until the figure is drawn (see [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77122190/3501128)) so here I force a draw with `draw_without_rendering` in order to line up the annotation with the label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
img = plt.imshow(data, cmap='viridis')
color_bar = plt.colorbar(img, orientation='vertical')

color_bar.set_label('Color Bar Label', rotation=270, labelpad=15)
color_bar_label = color_bar.ax.yaxis.label

plt.gcf().draw_without_rendering()

plt.annotate('Right-Aligned Text', (1, 1.02),
             xycoords=(color_bar_label, color_bar.ax),
             ha='right', va='center')

plt.show()
```

If you want to line the text up with the rightmost artist without knowing *a priori* what that artist is, you could find the extent of all combined artists with `get_tight_bbox`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
img = plt.imshow(data, cmap='viridis')
color_bar = plt.colorbar(img, orientation='vertical')

color_bar.set_label('Color Bar Label', rotation=270, labelpad=15)

fig_bbox = plt.gcf().get_tightbbox()
rightmost = fig_bbox.max[0] * 72  # Convert position in inches to points

plt.annotate('Right-Aligned Text', (rightmost, 1.02),
             xycoords=('figure points', color_bar.ax),
             ha='right', va='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've incorporated this into my code, and the first method perfectly aligns the text with the rightmost artist. However, it also adds a huge amount of whitespace (equal to the width of the text) between the main plot and the color bar. Do you have any thoughts on why this could be? Defining zorder doesn't overcome it.

Comment: I see the same amount of whitespace with or without an annotation.  Are you using a layout engine?

Comment: Ah ha! Perfect, thank you. I was using constrained_layout=True which was introducing the additional whitespace. With this removed, your solution works perfectly. Thank you for your help.